# Not able to import LAS file into PostGIS from PDAL with filter

Tags: postgis, pdal, postgresql-10

I'm not able to import LAS file into PostGIS from PDAL with filters.
There is no error message from PDAL, and couldn't find any relevant errors in
PostgreSQL log files, except these errors:

```
2019-09-19 00:00:28.804 +08 [5400] CONTEXT:  SQL function "pc_envelopegeometry" during inlining
    automatic analyze of table "postgis_25_sample.sch.table1"
2019-09-19 00:00:28.805 +08 [5400] ERROR:  function pc_envelopeasbinary(public.pcpatch) does not exist at character 27
2019-09-19 00:00:28.805 +08 [5400] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
2019-09-19 00:00:28.805 +08 [5400] QUERY:  
            SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKB(PC_EnvelopeAsBinary($1))

2019-09-19 00:00:28.805 +08 [5400] CONTEXT:  SQL function "pc_envelopegeometry" during inlining
    automatic analyze of table "postgis_25_sample.sch.table2"
2019-09-19 00:00:28.818 +08 [5400] ERROR:  function pc_envelopeasbinary(public.pcpatch) does not exist at character 27
2019-09-19 00:00:28.818 +08 [5400] HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
2019-09-19 00:00:28.818 +08 [5400] QUERY:  
            SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKB(PC_EnvelopeAsBinary($1))
...
```

I'm using PostgreSQL version 10.10, PostGIS version 2.5.1, pointcloud_postgis ver.1.2.0, pdal 1.7.2 (git-version: Release), Windows 10 version 1903.

The LAS file is about 50GB.  I've 64GB Ram and set 300GB virtual memory.

I'm using these PDAL filters:

```
    {
    "type":"filters.pmf",
      "initial_distance":"0.8",  
        "max_window_size":"20"
  },
 {
      "type":"filters.range",
      "limits":"Classification[2:2]"
    },  
    {
      "type":"filters.divider",
      "capacity":100000000
    },

    {
      "type":"filters.chipper",
      "capacity":600
    },
```

What could cause the errors, how to solve the PostgreSQL errors, and where do I get the PDAL error logs?

Comment: You don't have a version of pc_envelopeasbinary installed.  This may have been deprecated or is unavailable for another reason in the version of pdal you have installed.

Comment: I don't know anything about PDAL, but this kind of error often comes from incorrect path settings. What does `SHOW search_path`; show. Also, what does  `\df+ pc_envelopeasbinary` show? If there is no function defintion showing, or if it is in a schema not in your search path, that is likely the issue.

Comment: @John, SHOW search_path; show: "$user", public, tiger.  Under public schema, there is a function defined: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pc_envelopeasbinary(
 p pcpatch)
    RETURNS bytea
    LANGUAGE 'c'

    COST 1
    IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
AS '$libdir/pointcloud-1.2', 'pcpatch_envelope_as_bytea'
;